# call wcf cross domain in asp.net mvc with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

i create project with Agency name in asp.net mvc and create other project in same solution with LoginServices for wcf service,and now i want call wcf method with jquery but i get error

my interface

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILoginServices
    {

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    string HelloWorld(string personName);

}
```

my services.svc

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

public class LoginServices : ILoginServices
{


    public string HelloWorld(string personName)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        // you are not returning data in proper JSON format, wrap the text in
        // an anonymous object before serializing.
        return serializer.Serialize(new { text = "Hello " + personName });
    }

}
```

my LoginService web.config

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"
          automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="address" value="localhost"/>
    <add key="pascaladdress" value="localhost"/>
    <add key="sms" value="0" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

and my ajax

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $("#test").click(function () {
        var personName = "John";
        var dataIn = '{"personName":"' + personName + '"}';
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:18169/LoginServices.svc/HelloWorld",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataIn,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#response").html(jsonData.text);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error: " + error);
            }
        });
    })
})
```

but i get this error

```
400 Bad Request
```

in chrome my requesturl is

```
http://localhost:18169/LoginServices.svc/HelloWorld?callback=jQuery110206046013286612855_1465972517580&{%22personName%22:%22John%22}&_=1465972517581
```

how can do ajax with cross domain with my code?

thank's for your help